# How to select 2 rows at a time in Data Grid in WPF via MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls

My date Grid Consists of rows with a list of transactions details.

1 st two rows  consist of **Transaction Number : 1** Details 
2nd two Rows  consist of **Transaction Number : 2** Details and Goes on.

So if i select Transaction Number : 1 Row Automatically next row will be selected (with Trans Num:1).
the Same rule Applies to all the Rows with Transaction Numbers.

So how can achieve this in wpf to make visible to user that he has selected 2 Rows. I have to implement it using MVVM Pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well to tell the Data Grid to select more then one Row is simple "SelectionMode=Extended". But I think you'll need to add a behavior to get the second row selected automatically. Something like this ( most is hard coded so it's may not working perfectly ;)

create a new class and call it DataGridSelectMulti.cs

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Text;

namespace DataGridSelectMulti
{
    public class DataGridSelectMulti: CommandBehaviorBase<DataGrid>
    {
               protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();
            this.AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged);
        }

        void AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is DataGrid)
            {
                DataGrid grid = (sender as DataGrid);
                if (grid.SelectedItem != null)
                {
                    grid.UpdateLayout();
                    //TODO
                    // Something like grid.SelectedItems = List
                }
            }

        }



        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            base.OnDetaching();
            this.AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -= new SelectionChangedEventHandler(AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged);
        }
    }



XAML

<Grid>
<DataGrid name='' Selcted...>
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <my1:DataGridSelectMulti/>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
<DataGrid .Columns />
</DataGrid >
</Grid>
```

Comment: Could you please provide me any sample on how to add the behaviour(in MVVM)

Comment: and btw. if u want to implement it in MVVM-pattern better create a new class library where u can add all your converter, behavior's, and so on...